# Creating big size diagonal matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, out-of-memory, diagonal

I have a 512x512 random matrix which I want to put elements of it on the main diagonal of another matrix which elements are all zero so that my diagonal matrix would be 262144x262144.Of course it gives me low memory error.I also tried sparse function but it also does not work.Can anyone help me with this?
here is the code:

```
A=randn(512,512);
A=A(:);
Z=sparse(diag(A));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an expert on `sparse` matrices, but looking at the [`docs`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html), I believe you can do something like this -

```
sparse(1:262144,1:262144,A(:))
```

Sample run -

```
>> A
A =
     1     7     4
     8     7     6
     9     7     2
>> n = 9
n =
     9
>> sparse(1:n,1:n,A(:))
ans =
   (1,1)        1
   (2,2)        8
   (3,3)        9
   (4,4)        7
   (5,5)        7
   (6,6)        7
   (7,7)        4
   (8,8)        6
   (9,9)        2
>> full(sparse(1:n,1:n,A(:)))
ans =
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     8     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     9     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     7     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     7     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     7     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     4     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     6     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     2
```

Comment: That's exactly how you'd do it.  The first and second inputs are 1D vectors that define the row and column locations that are non-zero.  The third input is another vector that tells you what each value would be for each row column pair.